# how to display price with symbol using money-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, currency

Given this simple `Money` object query

```
Money.new(1000, "USD").to_s
=> "10.00"
```

How can I display the value with its symbol? I'm aware I can call `money_object.symbol` but some currencies place the symbol before and other after the value. Im pretty sure there should be some easy method already for this? Haven't find it by reading into the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency) has `number_to_currency` which should do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

if you are using [`money-rails`](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails), you have a lots of helpers:

- the currency_symbol helper method

  ```
  <%= currency_symbol %>
  ```

This will render a span dom element with the default currency symbol.

- the humanized_money helper method

  ```
  <%= humanized_money @money_object %>
  ```

This will render a formatted money value without the currency symbol and without the cents part if it contains only zeros (uses :no_cents_fi_whole flag).

- humanize with symbol helper

  ```
  <%= humanized_money_with_symbol @money_object %>
  ```

This will render a formatted money value including the currency symbol and without the cents part if it contains only zeros.

- get the money value without the cents part

  ```
  <%= money_without_cents @money_object %>
  ```

This will render a formatted money value without the currency symbol and without the cents part.

- get the money value without the cents part and including the currency symbol

  ```
  <%= money_without_cents_and_with_symbol @money_object %>
  ```

This will render a formatted money value including the currency symbol and without the cents part.