# Money-Rails not formatting thousands correctly for salaries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, money-rails

When I use money-rails for converting the integer hourly_wage_salary_cents column into a thousands money object. It removes 2 zeros from the number itself. Instead of getting $50,000, I am getting $500.00 or $500. How can I format the money object to include the correct comma places for numbers larger than hundreds.

show.html.erb

```
<h6><%= fa_icon 'money' %> Salary/Wage</h6>
        <p>
          <%= money_without_cents @job.hourly_wage_salary_cents %>
        </p>
```

job model

```
monetize :hourly_wage_salary, :as => "hourly_wage_salary_cents"
```

Comment: by default when you create  a money object with `new` method, it takes that amount as cents. (or any other subunit). so, `Money.new(5000, 'USD')` is actually five thousand cents and this is  50 bucks, not 5 thousand.

Answer (score 0):

By default the money object will have the amount in cents. So, you need to take this in account when saving or setting the value.

You can find more details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634084/how-to-display-price-with-symbol-using-money-rails). 
Some options to do the formatting:

- the `number_to_currency` from [ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html)
- `humanized_money @money_object` from `money_rails` [helpers](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#helpers)